# asignar propiedades al elemento pulsado

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach

he realizado este codigo que me aplica un background si hago click sobre el numero seleccionado, pero problema que tengo es que al pulsar varios botones se quedan con la propiedad asignada , solo quiero que se quede el fondo en el número seleccionado no, no en todos los que marco.

```
let num = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let submit = document.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"]');

   num.forEach((nums) => {
  nums.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    num = nums.textContent;
    span.textContent = num;
    nums.classList.add("checket");
  });
});

submit.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", (btn) => {
    btn.preventDefault();
    submit[0].addEventListener("click", mostrarcarta);
    submit[1].addEventListener("click", quitarcarta);
  });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Simplemente usa `classList.remove()` en todos los botones que tienes en `num` excepto el seleccionado. Ten cuidado porque el selector abarca a todos los botones. También podrías compartir el código HTML y CSS también para poder visualizarlo.

Comment: como uso puedo usar la propiedad classList.remove() en  los botones , menos en el seleccionado?

Comment: Vamos, piensa un momento. Puedes recorrer el arreglo con un ciclo y con un if y una comparación ves si se trata del mismo botón. Si es así no haces nada, sino le quitas la clase. Y el código va como texto, no imagen.

Comment: nose , como plantear el condicional que me indicas.